# from std::vector to adept::avector

Tags: c++, rcpp

I would like to embed some adept optimization in a package for R. See minimal example below. I need to pass values of x (and b) to that function. By default, they come in as Rcpp:NumericVector, which is easy to translate to a std::vector or array of doubles, e.g.

```
std::vector<double> inx_std(inx.begin(),inx.end());
double* inx_d = inx_std.data();
```

However, I am having trouble passing this into the avector a. `avector a = inx_d` does not work. I created a for loop, and everything works, but there must be a better way to do this.

Code example below.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "adept_source.h"
#include <adept_arrays.h>                

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace adept;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector run(NumericVector inx, NumericVector inb) {
  int inxsize=inx.size();       // dim of gradient
  NumericVector out(inxsize);   // output vector

  //adept main 

  Stack stack;                    // Object to store differential statements
  aVector x(inxsize);             // Independent variables: active vector with inxsize elements
  aVector b(inxsize);             // Independent variables: active vector with inxsize elements
  for(int i=0; i<inxsize; i++) {  // Fill vector
    x[i]=inx(i);
    b[i]=inb(i);
  }

  stack.new_recording();          // Clear any existing differential statements

  //function to be differentiated 
  aReal J = sum(log(x)/log(b));   // Compute dependent variable: L3-norm in this case


  //adept main
  J.set_gradient(1.0);             // Seed the dependent variable
  stack.reverse();                 // Reverse-mode differentiation

  //return gradient from adept to R
  for(int i=0; i<inxsize; i++) {
    out[i]=x[i].get_gradient();
  }

  return out;
}
```

Comment: ? `inx_d` is a pointer to a double. How do you expect assigning that to a vector would work?? E.g. `vector<double> a = inx_d` will also not work. I'm not familiar with adept, but did you try `avector a(inx_std.cbegin(), inx_std.cend());`?

Comment: JHBonarius: Well, I don't know the constructors for adept::aVector. I am new to this, and I find the documentation hard to follow. I tried `  aVector x(inx_std.begin(), inx_std.end());` but it yields 'no matching function call to 'adept::Array<1, double, true>::Array(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator)'

Comment: try `aVector a(inx_std.data(), dimensions(inx_std.size()))`, according to [page 25 of the documentation](http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/clouds/adept/adept_documentation_2.0.pdf). Note **"this relies on the existing data not
being deallocated for the lifetime of the Vector."!!!!**

Comment: Thanks, getting closer maybe. Page 25 provides the `Vector x(ptr, dimensions(n));' example, though it is not explicit about whether aVector behaves the same way. In tried using inx_std.data() as you suggest, but the error message is cryptic [no type named 'STATIC_ASSERTION_HAS_FAILED' in 'struct adept::Array<Rank, Type, IsActive>::Array(Type*, const adept::ExpressionSize<MyRank>&) [with int Rank = 1; Type = double; bool IsActive = true]::ERROR_CANNOT_CONSTRUCT_ACTIVE_ARRAY_WITHOUT_GRADIENT_INDEX']. 
I also tried pointing to the double* pointer inx_d, similar issue.

Comment: `adept::Vector a(inx_d, dimensions(inxsize) );`  works -   `adept::aVector a(inx_d, dimensions(inxsize) );`  does not work

Comment: Got it to work, but I need an additional line of code:
`std::vector<double> inx_std(inx.begin(),inx.end());
  adept::Vector inxV(inx_std.data(), dimensions(inxsize) );  
  adept::aVector x = inxV;`
Not sure if it's the best solution, but looks ok for my purposes. So first it created an adept::Vector, and then an aVector from that. Still confused on the aVector class. Thanks much JHBonarius!

Comment: Good for you. You can answer your own question. Maybe it will help someone else. The `aVector` class doesn't exist: it's just a typdef of the `adept:array` class, as shown [here](https://github.com/rjhogan/Adept-2/blob/master/include/adept/array_shortcuts.h). There's much information in de documentation I linked before.

Comment: This discussion looks fruitful -- we are in essence doing the same with RcppArmadillo: zero-overhead no copy instantiation re-using the memory of the R object and trusting it won't go away (which is totally fair for our purposes of calling from R, and returning to it).  You could do the same here.  However, if you first convert to `std::vector<double>` then you incur a copy.  Guess getting it working first is the initial goal...

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. 'Fruitful' sounds positive. Yes, first goal was to get it to work. I have now updated the code in the main post, and I skip the std::vector conversion step. Also, since only derivatives wrt x are computed, b is now just a adept::Vector, not aVector. adept::Vector can be created with a pointer to the NumericVector without problem. The only thing I haven't resolved is getting to the aVector directly, but I guess I have to read up on typedefs.

Comment: I've rolled-back your edit: "updated the code in the main post" is ***not*** how StackOverflow works: if you solved your problem yourself, you should add it as an *Answer*, not edit it in your question. See: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you have a ***new*** question, you should open a new topic. Also "Further suggestions for improvements welcome." is not a good question for StackOverflow: You have [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on helpful comments from JHBonarius and Dirk's hint regarding pointers, I have created the following minimal example for using adept in R via Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <adept_source.h>
#include <adept_arrays.h>                

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace adept;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector run(NumericVector inx, NumericVector inb, double gamma) {
  int inxsize=inx.size();       // dim of gradient
  NumericVector out(inxsize);   // output vector

  //convert inputs to adept arrays
  adept::Vector inxV(inx.begin(), dimensions(inxsize) );  
  adept::Vector b(inb.begin(), dimensions(inxsize) );  

  //adept main 
  Stack stack;                    // Object to store differential statements
  adept::aVector x = inxV;

  stack.new_recording();          // Clear any existing differential statements

  //function to be differentiated
  aReal J = gamma*sum(log(x)/log(b));   // Compute dependent variable


  //adept main
  J.set_gradient(1.0);             // Seed the dependent variable
  stack.reverse();                 // Reverse-mode differentiation


  //return gradient from adept to R
  for(int i=0; i<inxsize; i++) {
    out[i]=x[i].get_gradient();
  }

  return out;
}

/*** R
run(1:3,rep(exp(1),3),1)
*/
```

Key elements of the solution are:

(1) Creating an adept::Vector, using the appropriate constructor with a pointer to the input Rcpp::Numericvector called inx:

```
adept::Vector inxV(inx.begin(), dimensions(inxsize) )
```

(2) The vector of interest (for which we want to compute the partial derivatives) can then be turned into an 'active' vector:

```
adept::aVector x = inxV;
```

Comment: Very nice. Glad you have it working.  If you want to write it up for the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/), we always take interesting contributions!